# DNSSEC - How many DS records are ordinary?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dnssec

I thought that I need two DS records to deposit at my domain registrar. But one big dns provider just gave me one DS record. Verisign DNSSEC debugger says, everything is correct. But I am confused, because dnssec-keygen (DNSSEC key generation tool) gave me always two DS records. I have my doubts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get 2 `DS` records, it is basically always because one of them contains a [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash and the other one contains a [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash. Look at the third integer in the textual representation of the DS record. [1 means SHA-1 and 2 means SHA-256](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4509.txt).

If both types exist, verifiers may use whichever one they like, though they should use the strongest one they understand. That means verifiers will use SHA-256 if they support it, or SHA-1 otherwise.

The SHA-1 version of the DS record need only be present to support older verifiers that do not understand SHA-256. Hopefully such verifiers are vanishingly rare, so you should be fine with just a SHA-256 DS record.

If you were giving only a SHA-1 record and no SHA-256 record, you should ideally ask for a SHA-256 one, but don't worry about it too much: for now SHA-1 is probably still acceptable.

Comment: Do I use the DS records of the KSK or ZSK keys?

Comment: The DS records belong to the KSK key. The tools like `dnssec-signzone` that handle the generation for you automatically should also handle this automatically.